# How to name Foreign Key with @CollectionTable in JPA?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I need help with resolving our problem with naming FK in JPA. We have one embeddable entity e.g. **Foo** which is used as collection in another one entity **Bar**.

embeddable entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class Foo{
    @Column(name = "foo1")
    private String foo1;

    @Column(name = "foo2")
    private String foo2;
}
```

main entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bar")
public class Bar {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "foos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "foo_bar_fk"), nullable = false))
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

When I generated tables in database (postgres) foreign key is called fdk44l345k64 instead foo_bar_fk. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `CollectionTable` has "foreignKey", so why are you setting that of `JoinColumn`??

Comment: @BillyFrost to define its properties

Comment: and why dont you use the `foreignKey` of `@CollectionTable` NOT the `foreignKey` of `@JoinColumn`???

Comment: @BillyFrost thank you it works, but I don't understant how it works. Why I can't set it in JoinColumn if I need set name FK for that join column?

Comment: Because the `foreignKey` on that annotation is for something else! Just set the name on `foreignKey` in `@CollectionTable`

Comment: @ElementCollection isn't appropriate there, it's meant for non-entities (so Bar wouldn't work)
And why does Bar have a collection of itself??

Comment: "Because foreign key on that annotation is for something else" very informative.